# Svnsync slave to master

Tags: svn, svnsync, svnserve

Hj, alll
 - I'm have to svn 1.6 on 2 server centos : Master: 1.9, Slave: 1.12
 - I'm use svnsync create a slave repo of master repos.
 - All svnsync Master server to Slave server very good.

- Have a problem is SVN Master die? i'm change use to Slave server.
- But after svn Master = OK, i'm want to sync db Slave -->> Master????

And help will be greate, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> i'm want to sync db Slave -->> Master

It's impossible, svnsync is unidirectional sync. You **must**

- Create dump of *added revisions* on slave
- Load dump to master

Comment: Second option, make the slave the new master and press forward.